# Include static CSS file last (for branding)

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-cli

We have an embedded web app that has a requirement that it needs to be able to be re-branded by an integrator after the app is built and deployed. The requirement states that the integrator may upload a `branding.css` which will override existing styles with the brand colors, etc.

The problem is that it seems impossible to accommodate this requirement with Angular and Angular CLI. I wanted to double check here before I write a hacky post-processing python script that gets the job done.

Basically, all I want is after doing an `ng build`, I want my `index.html` to look like this:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title [translate]="'index.title'"></title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link href="styles.f14ea32bf407dc2d4831.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="branding.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
```

That way `branding.css` is last which means any classes in there will override the ones in the styles bundle and the integrator can simply overwrite that one file with the partner's branding. Is there a way to do this (or similar)?

Comment: https://shekhargulati.com/2018/01/16/dynamically-loading-css-in-angular-5-application/ (sorry, I can't find in stackoverflow, I know that exist the response)

Comment: OP doesn't want to import a css file. They just want the link to be there so that their customers can add the CSS file @Eliseo

Comment: I guess persuading the branding team to go with CSS variables is a no-go? :)

Comment: You could add the `<link>` at the end of `<body>`, since Angular will inject the other styles into `<head>`

Comment: @LazarLjubenović not necessarily. In this case you are suggesting using local variables for key branding styles so that `branding.css` can just contain `:root` with variable overrides (so that it no longer matters in which order the CSS files are included?)

Comment: @Gillespie Well if you know in advance what can be parametrized, CSS vars is the way to go. It requires more work from you at the start, but it would probably pay off on the long run because, trust me, that branding team is going to swarm you with questions "can you add a class", "can you change order", "can you wrap in a div" soon enough. With vars, you bound them to what can be changed. The order of files wouldn't matter since they would define the variables and you'd have a valid fallback in CSS anyway for non-supporting browsers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also try loading css dynamically

```
this.http.get('assets/test.css', { responseType: 'text' })
  .subscribe((css) => {
    let head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    let link = document.createElement('style');
    link.type = 'text/css';
    link.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
    head.appendChild(link);
  });
```

in angular.json,

```
 ...
 "extractCss": true,
 "assets": [
   "src/assets" /* "src/favicon.ico", other assets */
 ],
 ...
```

demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e7htks?file=src%2Fassets%2Ftest.css
you can tweak test.css and refresh the embed page to see actual effect.

Given css is nothing but plain text here, you can also let user upload css, have it sanitized and served over an endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

You could add `<link href="branding.css" rel="stylesheet" />` at the end of `<body>` instead of in `<head>`. Not a great practice, but it might make sense in this case.

Your source index.html:

```
<head>
  <!--Base, title, meta tags-->
</head>
<body>
  <my-app></my-app>
  <!--Branding style overrides-->
  <link href="branding.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</body>
```

And after building, you should get:

```
<head>
  <!--Base, title, meta tags-->
  <link href="styles.f14ea32bf407dc2d4831.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
  <my-app></my-app>
  <!--Branding style overrides-->
  <link href="branding.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js">
</body>
```

Since Angular injects styles into `<head>`, your branding css will occur later in the document and will have higher specificity.

[MDN says...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link)

> A `<link>` element can occur either in the `<head>` or `<body>` element, depending on whether it has a link type that is body-ok. For example, the stylesheet link type is body-ok, and therefore `<link rel="stylesheet">` is permitted in the body. However, this isn't a good practice to follow; it makes more sense to separate your `<link>` elements from your body content, putting them in the `<head>`.